# Combine several multiple binary variables into 1 in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Here is the story:

I have a data set with many binary variables (1 = yes and 0 = no). The thing is that many of those variables are the same, but just written differently. 
Example:

- twins

  - gemelli
  - DCDA
  - MCDA
  - twin DCDA
  - twin MCDA
  - ...

It all depends on the doctor/his habits/his mood/his literacy. If an observation gets a "1" for any of those above variables, it means that there will be twins (pregnancy). Now to make some predictions and stuff about twins, I need to group all those observations that have a "1" in any of those possible variables (sometimes even in 2 of them).

Here is what I tried:

```
features <- mutate(features,
                   TWIN_P = ifelse("twins" == 1 |
                                      "gemelli" == 1 |
                                      "DCDA" == 1 |
                                      "MCDA" == 1 |
                                      "twin DCDA" == 1 |
                                      "twin MCDA" == 1 , 
                                      "1", "0"))
```

But when I look at the new variable TWIN_P I get 0 twins... Which is of course impossible.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The binary variables are numerical. I tried to do this in between "" or without them. But nothing really worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't quote the variable names. You can use backticks `` for those with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what your dataframe looks like, so here's a stand-in:

```
twins <- rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.2) 
gemelli <- rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.2)
DCDA <- rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.2)
MCDA <- rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.2)
twin_DCDA <- rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.2)
twin_MCDA <- rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.2)

df1 <- data.frame(twins, gemelli, DCDA, MCDA, twin_DCDA, twin_MCDA)
```

Then `rowSums` on those greater than 0, which will output `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Put that into `as.integer` which will convert `TRUE`/`FALSE` into `0` or `1`:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    TWIN_P = as.integer(rowSums(.)>0)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Edward - don't quote the variable names. Since you have two variable names with a space, you can use backticks: `` `twin DCDA` `` Generally, you should try to avoid spaces in column names.

In addition, here is another approach with base R to checking if any column value is 1:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(matrix(rbinom(36, 1, .1), ncol = 6))
colnames(df) = c('twins', 'gemelli', 'DCDA', 'MCDA', 'twin DCDA', 'twin MCDA')

cbind(df, TWIN_P = as.numeric(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 1))))
```

**Output**

```
  twins gemelli DCDA MCDA twin DCDA twin MCDA TWIN_P
1     0       0    0    0         0         1      1
2     0       0    0    1         0         1      1
3     0       0    0    0         0         0      0
4     0       0    0    0         0         0      0
5     1       1    0    0         0         0      1
6     0       0    0    1         0         0      1
```